# Linq-to-SQL: Trying to create a new version of an entity but get 'Cannot add an entity that already exists'

Tags: linq-to-sql

I have the following table

```
[TestModule]
ProductId uniqueidentifier primarykey
ModuleId uniqueidentifier primarykey
LastEdited timestamp primarykey
LastEditor uniqueidentifier
LastEditComment nvarchar(200)
CheckedOutTo uniqueidentifier
... other fields ...
```

The class is defined as follows:

```
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public Guid ProductGuid { get; private set; }

    [Column(IsPrimaryKey = true)]
    public Guid ModuleGuid { get; private set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// date of last edit
    /// </summary>
    [Column(IsPrimaryKey=true)]
    public DateTime LastEditDate { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Guid of last editor
    /// </summary>
    [Column]
    public Guid LastEditorGuid { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary of last changes
    /// </summary>
    [Column]
    public string LastEditNote { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Current editor. Null if checked in
    /// </summary>
    [Column(CanBeNull=true)]
    public Guid CheckedOutByGuid { get; set; }
```

I want to be able to select a TestModule entity, make some modifications and insert it as a new entity. The goal is to have a history of changes.

However, I have not been able to insert the changed object. I get an error message 'Cannot add an entity that already exists'. Before inserting the object I set the LastEdited property to a new value (Now) and would expect that, because the property is a primary key, it should define a new entity. This does not seem to be the case.

Can any one help me to understand what is going on here? What is it that actually defines an entity? The primary keys? The object identity? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the entity is identified in the first instance by the object itself and not the object's primary key properties. I found that cloning the object was the way to go forward. Trying to insert a cloned object was picked up as an error if the primary key properties remained unchanged, which is to be expected. Modifed objects are updated in the database when the `Context.SubmitChanges()` method is called. All very logical, I guess - once you get the hang of it..

Answer (score 0):

You could try to set

```
 db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false
```

on the data context when you select your entity.